# Java Transformer error: Could not compile stylesheet

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I'm want to transform a XML with XSLT in Java. For that I'm using the `javax.xml.transform` package. However, I get the exception `javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Could not compile stylesheet`. This is the code I'm using:

```
public static String transform(String XML, String XSLTRule) throws TransformerException {

    Source xmlInput = new StreamSource(XML);
    Source xslInput = new StreamSource(XSLTRule);

    TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(xslInput); // this is the line that throws the exception

    Result result = new StreamResult();
    transformer.transform(xmlInput, result);

    return result.toString();
}
```

Note that I marked the line which throws the exception.

When I enter the method, the value of `XSLTRule` is this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version='1.0'
 xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'
 xmlns:msxsl='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt'
 exclude-result-prefixes='msxsl'
 xmlns:ns='http://www.ibm.com/wsla'>
    <xsl:strip-space elements='*'/>
    <xsl:output method='xml' indent='yes'/>
    <xsl:template match='@* | node()'>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select='@* | node()'/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/ns:SLA
                            /ns:ServiceDefinition
                               /ns:WSDLSOAPOperation
                                  /ns:SLAParameter[@name='Performance']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Wich exception did you catch?

Comment: It is `javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException`. I edited my original post, it is there now.

Comment: Why your last template is empty ?

Comment: Because that element should be deleted. It finds the element, but doesn't copy it. This XSLT should work, I used it before while I was working in .NET.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [constructor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/stream/StreamSource.html#StreamSource%28java.lang.String%29)

```
public StreamSource(String systemId)
```

Construct a StreamSource from a URL. I think you're passing the content of the XSLT instead. Try this:

```
File xslFile = new File("path/to/your/xslt");
TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Templates xsl = factory.newTemplates(new StreamSource(xslFile));
```

You must also set the `OutputStream` that your `StreamResult` will write to:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Result result = new StreamResult(baos);
transformer.transform(xmlInput, result);
return baos.toString();
```

Comment: Alternatively, just change `new StreamSource(XSLTRule)` to `new StreamSource(new StringReader(XSLTRule))`

Comment: thanks a lot! but i still have a problem with the `Result result = new StreamResult();`. What to do there?

Comment: @Ivan: what problem do you have with `Result result = new StreamResult();`?

Comment: @Michael For the line `transformer.transform` I get this exception: `javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Result object passed to ''{0}'' is invalid.`I did the same thing for the variable XML as for XSLTRule.

Comment: @Ivan: I see: I've edited my answer to address that problem too.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to contruct a stream from the xslt string you have and then use it as the stream source

```
InputStream xslStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(XSLTRule.getBytes("UTF-8"));
Source xslInput = new StreamSource(xslStream);
```

To get the result to a string :

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Result result = new StreamResult(bos);
    transformer.transform(xmlInput, result);
    String s = new String(bos.toByteArray());
    System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: thanks a lot! but i still have a problem with the `Result result = new StreamResult();`. What to do there?

Answer (score 0):

To use XSLTC,  put xalan.jar(2.5), serializer.jar, xml-apis.jar, and xercesImpl.jar on your classpath .

Comment: Don't do this. All those packages (from the Xerces project) have been abandoned since 2010. The code now lives in the JVM.